# How to identify the file type even though the file-extension has been changed?

Tags: java, filesystems, file-extension, magic-numbers

Files are categorized by file-extension. So my question is, how to identify the file type even the file extension has been changed.

For example, i have a video file with name `myVideo.mp4`, i have changed it to `myVideo.txt`. So if i double-click it, the preferred text editor will open the file, and won't open the exact content. But, if i play `myVideo.txt` in a video player, the video will be played without any problem.

I was just thinking of developing an application to determine the type of file without checking the file-extension and suggesting the software for opening the file. I would like to develop the application in Java.

Comment: Google "file headers" and "magic numbers"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Structure, magic numbers, metadata, strings and regular expressions, heuristics and statistical analysis... the tool will only be as good as the database of rules behind it.

Try DROID (**[Digital Record Object IDentification tool](https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/information-management/manage-information/policy-process/digital-continuity/file-profiling-tool-droid/)**) for identifying file types; Java, Net BSD-licensed. It is a free project of the National Archives UK, unrelated to Android. Source is available on Github and [Sourceforge](https://droid.sourceforge.net/). The DROID documentation is good, there's also a [getting started guide](https://www.dpconline.org/handbook/tool-demos/droid-demo) from the *Digital Preservation Coalition*.

See also **[Darwinsys file](http://darwinsys.com/file/)** and **[libmagic](https://www.dpconline.org/handbook/tool-demos/droid-demo)**.

Comment: +1 DROID is actually a very impressive library. I can't believe I forgot about it.

Comment: Is the project discontinued for some reason currently?

Comment: Linkrot, fixed. My misplaced faith in "digital continuity" adjusted accordingly...

Answer (score 6):

One of the best libraries to do this is [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/). It doesn't only read the file's header, it's also capable of performing content analysis to detect the file type. Using Tika is very simple, here's an example of detecting a file's type:

```
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.tika.Tika; //Including Tika

public class TestTika {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tika tika = new Tika();
        String fileType = tika.detect(new URL("http://example.com/someFile.jpg"));
        System.out.println(fileType);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool called [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) that does what you are after - it current supports 5033 different file types - and can be [trained](http://mark0.net/soft-tridscan-e.html) to add new types. On *nix systems, there's also the [`file`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29) command, which does something similar.

Comment: TrID is not platform-independant. I want to do it in platform independant way.

Comment: TrID claims to support Linux, though I can't say I've tried it myself.

Comment: Yeah it's true. But i can't use the same application using in Windows to do in *nix. That's why i am thinking to do using Java.

Answer (score 0):

well, its like having a database of file-format you want to read without looking for extension  in your app. Exactly as Linux does. So whenever you open a file, you need to check file-format database which type it belongs to. Though Not sure how will it work for different file types, but most of files have fixed header format, be it zip, pdf, mpg, avi, png, etc.. so this approach should work

Answer (score 0):

You could try [MimeUtil2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mime-util/), but it's quite old and though not up2date. The best way is still the file extension.

But the solution from Adam is not as bad as you think. You could build your platform independent solution using a wrapper around command line calls. I think you will get much better results using this method.

Comment: The project website is showing as unavailable. I was trying to achieve it in pure java.

Comment: Yes the Sourceforge page is the only available page.

Answer (score -3):

The following code snippet retrieves information about the file type

```
final File file = new File("file.txt");
System.out.println("File type is: " + new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(file));
```

Hopefully, it may help you

Comment: Does that actually work. Doc states "This class extends FileTypeMap and provides data typing of files **via their file extension**." But OP wants to "identify the file type even the **file extension has been changed**"